# How to move around Pandas Dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I've attached a screenshot.
I need some method to move the 'DATE' column to be aligned with the actual columns of the dataframes, which are SMA & Closing Price. I need to be able to use the date column as an X parameter for visualization later. Please let me know any way to line up the date with other columns.

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Comment: `total_df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First column is called `index` in pandas and for convert to column use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

But not necessary, if want use index later select it by `df.index`:

```
x = df.index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code posted by @jezrael to create a new index column with numerical values and align the date column along with the other columns. If you want to make the date column as the index again, you can try the following line of code:

```
total_df = total_df.set_index('date')
```

Comment: I don't look at the answers already posted before posting my own answers. If i know the answer, i just post it. My bad. I'm new to this place and still learning its ways. I'm sorry. It won't happen again.